# volley : multi in thread in RequestQueue Pool : ok. What about the reception?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am porting my app that was using an intentService to network. But IntentService is FIFO and thus request were dealt one by one ! that was an issue. So i am trying to implement Volley.

I have some doubts:

- How many error listener do I need (one on mainthread? several? one by request Type?) ?
- How many response< T> do I need ?
- At which level should I implement them?

Thanks